# Shortcodes and Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, shortcode

How do I get shortcodes to process properly in custom fields?

I've tried using the code below, but I cannot figure out where to place it ("button" is the name of the field):

```
<?php 
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', true) ) 
echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', $single = true));
?>
```

As of now, the shortcode is working in the sense that the button is displaying, but the shortcode text is displaying where the "buy now" button is supposed to be. See screenshot:

http://i.imgur.com/41vsr.png

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code into whatever page you are displaying the results of the shortcode.

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', true)); ?>
```

**Update:** Place it inside the loop

```
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', true) ) 
echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', $single = true));
```

Comment: That works now, but the shortcode is showing up along with the content. How do I get the shortcode to be hidden?